# JSAT: Data wrangling / manipulating

Tags: java, machine-learning

After building a prototype in `R` (using `dplyr`), I need to build a model that is deployable to our Java based server-infrastructure. Right now, I'm using the [`JSAT`](https://github.com/EdwardRaff/JSAT)-machine-learning library.

**What is the best way to wrangle data?**

None of the collection-like types from the `JSAT` package (`ClassificationDataSet`, `RegressionDataSet`, `DataSet`) seem to support even basic tasks like:

1. **Filtering** out datapoints based on conditions
2. **Splitting** the dataset into two (different sized) datasets, e.g. training and testing dataset
3. **Mutating** or adding new rows based on the values of other rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This isn't currently supported in JSAT, JSAT is a source of Machine Learning algorithms. Dataframe like operations are not a goal of the project in any way. I'm not sure why you would want to be filtering out data in a production system, there is no reason you couldn't do that in a better tool and then export the data to have JSAT build the model.

2) All DataSet objects inherit a `randomSplit` method that can do what you have asked for. An example of that is [here](http://jsatml.blogspot.com/2015/07/easier-hyperparameter-tuning.html).

3) See 1, I'm not sure what the use case is for adding "new rows based on the values of other rows". All the different DataSet classes support adding new data points, you just have to create them yourself.

source: I'm the author of JSAT